# Javascript OR conditional operator not working as expected

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I am experimenting with JavaScript conditions. In the code below, why is my first condition not returning true while the second one does?

Javascript:

```
   arr = [1,2,3];
        if (arr[0] !== (1 || 2)){console.log('true')}
        //undefined

        if (arr[0] !== (2 || 1)){console.log('true')}
        //true
```

Comment: what is the expected result of the above (pretending it would work this way)?

Comment: Try to run `console.log(1 || 2)` and `console.log(2 || 1)` and see what values they log.

Comment: "A common mistake when using the logical OR operator in conditional statements is to try to state the variable whose value you are checking once, and then give a list of values it could be to return true, separated by || (OR) operators" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/conditionals

Comment: A simpler way of understanding this is to just know that in any compound `if` statement each condition must be a complete condition that could be evaluated on its own. `(1 || 2)` is not a complete condition and, in this case will always evaluate to `true`.

Comment: It looks like you were actually trying to do something like: `[1,2].indexOf(arr[0])<0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`||` will evaluate to either:

- The first value, if it's truthy, or
- The final value (which may be either truthy or falsey)

Since `1` is truthy, `(1 || 2)` evaluates to `1`:

```
if (arr[0] !== (1 || 2)){console.log('true')}
// resolves to
if (1 !== (1 || 2)){console.log('true')} // resolves to
if (1 !== (1)){console.log('true')} // resolves to
if (1 !== 1){console.log('true')} // resolves to
if (false){console.log('true')}
```

So the first `if` statement does not go through. In the second case, `2 || 1` evaluates to the first truthy value of `2`, so the `if` statement succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need an array of numbers to check against and negate the check as well.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];

if (![1, 2].includes(arr[0])) {
    console.log(arr[0], 'is not', 1, 'or', 2);
}

if (![1, 2].includes(arr[2])) {
    console.log(arr[2], 'is not', 1, 'or', 2);
}
```